# Access System Information about another Mac?

Tags: macos

I have a MacBook Pro that's in bad shape. It was dropped on its corner.

The internal display is totally dead, and even connecting to an external monitor produces a distorted and unusable image.

The MacBook Pro is still file sharing though and I can connect to it from my iMac.

Any way to run System Profiler over the LAN?

Answer (score 2):

If you can ssh into the Mac, you can run `system_profiler` from the command line.

`system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType SPHardwareDataType` will get you general information.  You can get all sorts of information by using different switches.

For more info, type `man system_profiler`.

Comment: Thank you. I figured as much. The "Remote Login" option in System Preferences > Sharing must be disabled, unfortunately.